Facing an issue to convert timestamp to date in MySqlX.XDevAPI
I am trying to convert TimeStamp to Date format for easier comparisons to fetch records from my
MySqlX db but when I try to query it like this
DbDoc docData = new DbDoc(new { _startDate = startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), _endDate = endDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") });
collection.Find("DATE_FORMAT(TimeStamp, '%Y-%m-%d') >= :_startDate AND DATE_FORMAT(TimeStamp, '%Y-%m-%d') <= :_endDate").Bind(docData).Execute()

I get an error which says "Sequence contained null element\r\nParameter name: values
How do i solve this Unable to understand where I am going wrong
I am expecting the query to fetch all records on the db comparing only dates and leaving out the time part

Is this a c# or a MySQL error?

It is a mysql error

Forgive me but as far as I can see, it's unclear whether the error message pertaining to either. Could you use the same query to run directly in your MySQL and see if there's an error there? You should be able to get the exact MySQL error message (if any) then add into your question. You can use this as example https://dbfiddle.uk/XdQ_w15d
